# No module named django, but django is installed - miniconda has interfered with path?

Tags: python, django, macos, pip, miniconda

So to clarify, I had already got Django to work. The main thing I had done between installing Django and having this problem is that I installed miniconda3 and MySQLdb.

I'm running Python 3.7.1, pip 18.1 and as far as I know should have Django 2.1.4.

From /Users/me I run:

```
python3 -m django --version
```

and I get:

```
/Users/me/miniconda3/bin/python3: No module named django
```

From this I can see that the path seems to have been changed to miniconda, and I'm not sure how that has happened. If I run:

```
pip3 install Django
```

It then tells me:

```
Requirement already satisfied: Django in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.1.4)
```

Does anyone have either any idea of what could have happened and how to rectify it?

Comment: Do you work in a virtual environment?

Comment: No, just normal OS X

Comment: 1. You should be working in a vitual environment. 2. Change your path so OS python appears first

Comment: May I ask why I should be working in a virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a vitual environment :

   - cd /a/b
   - virtualenv -p C:/Python36-32/python.exe  venv
   - cd venv
   - pip install django
   - pip install ...

   go to your BASE_DIR

   - cd /projet_django_app/
   - python manage.py runserver

Comment: I've bee advised elsewhere to uninstall miniconda and use pip to install django instead. What is your opinion of that advice? 

I had miniconda as well as pip due to my lack of understanding of package installers.

Comment: I did not use miniconda. Since 3 years I use pip. It works well.
I think pip will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you were using another conda env and then activate another conda env (your current one) wihout deactivate your previous env.

I got the same issue. And I deactivated all evns, went all they way back to 'base', and then activate the particular env that has the package I installed it before, then it worked.